# VSC auto completion starts at wrong position

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I somehow changed a setting and not sure how to revert it.

usuall when i use emmet abbreviation i type

"back" and it suggests background-color , i click enter and it will auto complete the text and i can start writing the color.

but now every time i click enter my cursor position is in the middle of background-color. e.g
[example of wrong cursor position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVm3K.png)

so i will need click 3 times right and than i can write what i want.

anyone knows what settings this could be?